# How to cancel a job in Kotlin using job id passed to an API?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to build an API in Kotlin that accepts a job id and cancels the job if it is running. I know simple cancellation in Kotlin works like this:

```
val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    for (i in 0..1000) {
        delay(50)
        println("$i..")
    }
    println("Job is completed")
}
delay(500)
println("Cancelling")
job.cancel()
job.join()
println("Cancelled and done")
```

But what I want to do is

1. Have a StartJob API which starts a job and returns back the job id associated with this job. This id can be numeric or string.
2. Build a JobCancellation API which takes a job id as input and cancels that job if it is running. There can be multiple jobs with unique job ids running at the same time.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Barebones ID generator:

```
internal class IdProvider {
    private var previous = AtomicLong(-1L)

    fun next() = previous.addAndGet(1)
}
```

Then you can create a map of Job IDs to Jobs in your API:

```
class JobRegistry {
    private val idProvider = IdProvider()
    private val map = ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Job>()

    fun launch(
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, 
        start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, 
        block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
    ): Long {
        val id = idProvider.next()
        map[id] = scope.launch(context, start, block)
            .also { it.invokeOnCompletion { map.remove(id) } }
        return id
    }

    fun cancel(jobId: Long) {
        map[jobId]?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that code thread-safe? Would it make sense for IdProvider.previous to be an `AtomicLong` instead of a `Long`, and JobRegistry.map to be `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of an ordinary mutable map?

Comment: Those would be good improvements if you need to be able to use this from any thread. @dnault I was just showing a barebones strategy for it, but it does assume you only ever launch coroutines from the main thread.

Comment: How about the call to map.remove() -- is it guaranteed to run on the main thread?

Comment: No, good point. I updated it to use your suggestions.